# Complexity of factoring integers by trial division

Tags: computational-complexity, factoring

Ok, I have a real problem with understand the complexity of this algorithm:
set k=n;
while k!=1{
while True{
d=k/i;
if type(d)=integer{
i is a factor;
break;
}
}
}
So we go through the internal while loop a maximum of root n times, we go through the outer loop a times where a is the number of primes dividing n. I am using n formed of a product of two times so surely this has root(n) operations? That seems ridiculous because I thought this was an NP hard problem!

Comment: Some terminology nit-picking: this problem is not thought to be [NP hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness), only [NP intermediate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of $n$ considered in this problem when evaluating its time complexity is not the number itself, but rather the number of bits (equivalently, digits) the number has. When measured in that metric, the algorithm takes exponential time.

Comment: That makes so much more sense, am I right about the root n though?

Comment: @Mmm checking for a factor in this way takes at most $\sqrt{n}$ iterations. To find all factors you may have to do this up to $\log n$ times, but the factor finding loop gets shorter every time you find a factor. $\sqrt{n}\log n$ would be the bound I would go with.